# Laravel FormRequest response status code on failed validation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating validation (via FormRequest ) for my API and I need to change status code depending on failed validation rule (e.g. If id is string instead of int, get 400. If id doesn't exists, get 404).

I wanted to write something like that:

```
/**
 * Get the proper failed validation response for the request.
 *
 * @param  array  $errors
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function response(array $errors)
{
    $failedRules = $this->getValidatorInstance()->failed();

    $statusCode = 400;
    if (isset($failedRules['id']['Exists'])) $statusCode = 404;

    return response($errors, $statusCode);
}
```

However, $this->getValidatorInstance()->failed() returns empty array

- Why does $this->getValidatorInstance()->failed return empty array?
- How can I fix that? Is there some other way to return status code depending on failed validation rule?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting an empty array when your call `$this->getValidatorInstance()->failed()` is because it's actually resolving a new instance of `Validator`.

What you can do is call `passes()` on the new `Validator` instance which will then allow you to call `failed()` to get the rules:

```
$validator = $this->getValidatorInstance();
$validator->passes();
$failedRules = $validator->failed();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have the validator run twice you could override the `failedValidation` method to store the `Validation` instance in class:

```
protected $currentValidator;

protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $this->currentValidator = $validator;

    throw new ValidationException($validator, $this->response(
        $this->formatErrors($validator)
    ));
}

public function response(array $errors)
{
    $failedRules = $this->currentValidator->failed();

    $statusCode = 400;
    if (isset($failedRules['id']['Exists'])) $statusCode = 404;

    return response($errors, $statusCode);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, but in this case I validate data twice so it not helps me

Comment: I can't do that, bcs I get "Declaration of ...GetUser::response(array $errors, $validator) should be compatible with ...FormRequest::response(array $errors)" 

At least, i'm gonna to create my own class. Can u tell me, how i should do that? I mean, where should i create it? I thought i can create Facade, but i can't do that or docs does not say anything about that :)

Comment: @Ivan Oh yeah, of course it does. In that case you could add it to a property in your FormRequest and then reference it after. I've update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help. Nevermind, I'm gonna create new class, bcs I have to create twentyish classes like that :)

Comment: @Ivan Glad I could help! Just create one class with the above logic and have your twentyish classes extend it...